# Finding out additional transactions in two excels by using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel csv files as below

```
df1 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink'], 'Count': [1, 0, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=df1.keys())

df2 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink', 'SC-002_Signinlink'], 'Count': [2, 1, 2, 1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=df2.keys())
```

In df2 i could see that there is one extra transaction called 'SC-002_Signinlink' which is not there in df1. Can someone help me how to find only those extra transactions and print it to a file?

So far i had done below work to get the transactions...

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Transaction_Name', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'), how='outer')
```

Comment: This can be done with `isin`, `df2.loc[~df2.Transaction_Name.isin(df1.Transaction_Name),:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indicator=True in your merge :

```
df1 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink'], 'Count': [1, 0, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=df1.keys())

df2 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink', 'SC-002_Signinlink'], 'Count': [2, 1, 2, 1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=df2.keys())

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Transaction_Name', how='outer', indicator=True)

# As we do not merge on Count, we have 2 count columns (Count_x & Count_y)
# So we create a Count column which is the addition of the 2
df.Count_x = df.Count_x.fillna(0)
df.Count_y = df.Count_y.fillna(0)
print(df.dtypes)

df['Count'] = df.Count_x + df.Count_y

df = df.loc[df._merge != 'both', ['Transaction_Name', 'Count']]
print(df)

# Missing transactions list :
print(df.Transaction_Name.values.tolist())
```

**output for print(df.dtypes)**

```
Transaction_Name      object
Count_x              float64
Count_y                int64
_merge              category
dtype: object
```

**output for print(df)**

```
    Transaction_Name  Count
3  SC-002_Signinlink    1.0
```

**output for print(df.Transaction_Name.values.tolist())**

```
['SC-002_Signinlink']
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, The above code is giving me all the data as output by indicating the missed transaction name. Is it possible to get only missed transaction in the output.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it okay for you ? If not, please edit your answer with the expected output

Comment: Charles, when implemented the given code i am getting error "dfadd['Count'] = dfadd.Count_x + dfadd.Count_y" TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: It seems you have at least one string value in column Count_x or Count_y. What happens when you do print(df.dtypes) ?

Comment: Thanks Charles, i cleared it by doing "missing_df1_rows = merge_df[merge_df['_merge'] =='right_only'][df2.columns]"